# String after character in URL

Tags: python, jinja2

I have URL, e.g. `google.com/page1/page2/abc123` and my output should be `abc123`.

Comment: So, you want the last part of the URL when split by `/`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It would be simpler to understand, when posting a [example] of your Jinja-template, the given input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split the url address into a list and then get the last element of that list which would be what you need.

```py
url = "google.com/page1/page2/abc123"
splitted_url = url.split("/")
last_element = splitted_url[-1]
print(last_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. One would be to split the URL into tokens based on '/' then take the last token in the returned list. Another option would be to find the last occurrence of '/' in the string then slice the string accordingly.

```
URL = 'google.com/page1/page2/abc123'

print(URL.split('/')[-1])
print(URL[URL.rfind('/')+1:])
```